# read.csv crashes RStudio

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, read.csv

Help me figure out what I am doing wrong!

I have about 20 .csv files (product feeds) online. I used to be able to fetch them all. But now they crash R if I fetch more than one or two. File size is about 50K rows / 30 columns each.

I guess it's a memory issue but I've tried on a different computer with the exact same result.
Could it be some formatting in the files that make R use too much memory? Or what can it be?

If I run one of these everything is good. Two sometimes. Three and it almost certainly crashes

`a <- read.csv("URL1")`

`b <- read.csv("URL2")`

`c <- read.csv("URL3")`

I have tried specifying all sorts of stuff like:

`d <- read.csv("URL4",skipNul=TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE)`

I keep getting this message:

> R session aborted.
>   R encountered a fatal error.
>   The session was terminated.

We have some commercial software where I can fetch the same files without issues, so the files should be fine.
And my script was running twice daily for several months without issues

R version 3.6.1

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried checking the size of some of the files you can read in using `object.size(x)`?

Also, you could try `fread()` from the data.table package, which I've found to perform better with large files than the base R `read.csv()`

Comment: *Something* changed, and if you can figure out what, that will help a lot to solve the problem. If you jump straight to `URL4`, does it crash? I see you put the RStudio tag--is it relevant? Do you only see the problem in RStudio, but it works on the command line? How many MB or GB are the files if you just save them to disk? How are the files encoded?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response @eleventhend's suggestion of using fread() from the data.table library instead og read.csv() works. Thanks :) File sizes are 9-12mb and I have ~20 of them

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem out of the blue. Yesterday my code worked fine, today it keeps crashing on 1 csv file. I used readr read_csv2, which automatically converts it into a tibble. Splitting this procedure as proposed by @humane-arts seems to solve the issue. Using R version 4.0.3 and 4.0.5, filesize 248mb, 16gb memory.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue as well but with read_csv(). I haven't figured out what the exact cause is yet, but my best guess is that trying to read a file and write that file to a variable at the same time is too much for memory or CPU to handle.

Stemming from that guess, I tried this method and it has worked perfectly for me:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- read.csv("URL1") %>% as_tibble()

# you can use other data types instead of tibble. that is just my example.
```

The whole idea is to split the reading process from the writing process by separating them using a pipe. This makes sure that one must be finished before the next can start.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Rstudio still crashes. @eleventhend suggested trying fread() from the data.table library and that works for me.

Comment: It works for me (see comment at question as well). Unfortunately I am not able to pinpoint the exact problem.